# Deleting older images from external storage after a limit

Tags: android, caching, android-external-storage

I have implemented offline caching in my app and for that I am storing images in external storage.I want that once my cached images folder limit reaches 30 then it starts replacing the older images with new ones.For that i implemented following deletion algorithm-

```
 public static boolean deleteDir(File dir)
   {
        if (dir != null && dir.isDirectory())
        {
            String[] children = dir.list();

            if(children.length>30)
            {
                int exceed=children.length-30;

                for (int i = 0; i <exceed; i++)
                {

                    boolean success = deleteDir(new File(dir, children[i]));
                    if (!success)
                    {
                        return false;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Log.e("deleted","file deleted");
                    }

                }
            }

        }
        return dir.delete();
    }
```

But the above algorithm doesn't work as expected.It might deletes the newly added images.I also tried implementing below algorithm.But it also not working as expected.I failed to understand where I am going wrong.

```
public static boolean deleteDir(File dir)
       {
            if (dir != null && dir.isDirectory())
            {
                String[] children = dir.list();

                if(children.length>30)
                {
                    int exceed=children.length-30;
                    int destroy=(children.length-exceed)-1;
                    for (int i = children.length; i >destroy; i--)
                    {

                        boolean success = deleteDir(new File(dir, children[i]));
                        if (!success)
                        {
                            return false;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Log.e("deleted","file deleted");
                        }

                    }
                }

            }
            return dir.delete();
        }
```

Comment: how you find eldest file?

Comment: @Tkachuk_Evgen The files that are added in folder are arranged from eldest to new..so i want to delete the files at the beginning of folder.

Comment: @Tkachuk_Evgen Programmatically can I find how old file of external storage is?

Comment: @Tkachuk_Evgen I am assuming that the files in folder of user is arranged from old to new.I can't find any other way to find the oldest files in the folder of external storage programmatically?

Comment: JavaDoc not guaranted any specific order in array, so you must use File#listFiles() and then sort array 'Arrays#sort' with comparator which compare files by File#lastModified()

Comment: @Tkachuk_Evgen I am doing this in android..Can u help me with answer how should i proceed in that programmatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
public static void deleteDir(File dir) {
        if (dir != null && dir.isDirectory()) {
            File[] files = dir.listFiles();
            if (files.length > 30) {
                Arrays.sort(files, new Comparator<File>() {
                    @Override
                    public int compare(File o1, File o2) {
                        if (o1.lastModified() > o2.lastModified()) {
                            return 1;
                        } else if (o1.lastModified() < o2.lastModified()) {
                            return -1;
                        }
                        return 0;
                    }
                });
                for (int i = 0; i < files.length - 30; i++) {
                    files[i].delete();
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lott!!Glad if you can help me with this.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28893810/hiding-cached-data-from-user-so-that-user-cant-access-it