# Hiding cached data from user so that user can't access it

Tags: java, android, caching, offline-caching

I have implemented offline caching in my app and for that I am storing images in external storage.I am automatically deleting the cached data based on the available space in external storage and once the limit reaches the specified value.I want that cached data to be remain hidden from user so that user can't access it.Is it possible to hide the cached data from the user?Or is there any way i can make cached data folder visiblity invisible in external storage?

Comment: You could crypt the data

Comment: @A.S. I tried using dot(.) before the name of folder while creating folder to make the folder hidden..But then i am not able to fetch images from the folder when i am offline.

Comment: Why don't you want to use internal storage?

Comment: Why cant you get images from a hidden folder?

Comment: @greenapps I f i use internal storage will the  cached data remain hidden from user such that user can't access it?

Comment: Yes. Internal memory is hidden as long as the phone is not rooted.

Comment: @greenapps Hows internal memory hidden from user?We can access device storage in our mobile.We can access internal sd card of our device..??

Comment: Yes. But that is external memory. Instead of getExternalCacheDir() use getCacheDir() and you get something like /data/data/<packagename>/cache. Now try to look in it with a file axplorer and you wil see that /data is empty.